# Python string replace with regex substitution variable

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, where the substring `2.5` was incorrectly formed: `'It costs 2. 5. That is a lot.'`

How do I remove the space between the `2.` and the `5`?

I tried:

```py
s = 'It costs 2. 5. That is a lot.'
s = s.replace('. ', '.')
print(s) # It costs 2.5.That is a lot.
```

However, that also remove the correctly-placed space between the `5.` and `T`. I think I'm looking for a sed-style regex substitution variable, like `s/\. \([0-9]\)/.\1/g`. How do I do that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the string after it can start with a digit, you can match the dot after the second digit as well.

If you don't want to match newlines in between, you can match all whitespace chars without a newline.

```
\b(\d+\.)[^\S\r\n]+(\d+\.)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+\.)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits and a dot
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without a newline
- `(\d+\.)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits and a following dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rdMRCh/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LunrE2)

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2.

For example

```
import re
s = ("It costs 2. 5. That is a lot.\n"
    "It costs 2. 5 items, that is a lot.")
pattern = r"\b(\d+\.)[^\S\r\n]+(\d+\.)"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1\2", s))
```

Output

```
It costs 2.5. That is a lot.
It costs 2. 5 items, that is a lot.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
(?<=\d\.)\s+(?=\d)
```

As seen [here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xiBmvi/2)

## Explanation

I'm making use of positive lookbehinds and lookaheads in regex, which tell the regex to match one or more spaces `\s+` which are preceded by a digit and a period (given by `(?<=\d\.)`), and followed by a digit (given by `(?=\d)`)

[Here's a link to learn more about lookaheads and lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They're incredibly useful in so many problems, so I suggest you learn more about them.

---

## Python Implementation

```
import re

s = 'It costs 2. 5. That is a lot.'
s = re.sub(r"(?<=\d\.)\s+(?=\d)", "", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("(\d+). (\d+)", "\g<1>.\g<2>", s)
'It costs 2.5. That is a lot.'
```